# ASP.NET: How to handle all page redirection?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In an ASP.NET page, are there any practical ways to handle all of these following:

1. PostBack
2. Redirection when user click a link in the page
3. Redirection when user change url field in the browser

with just a single web control (or method)?

TQ

Comment: What do you mean by "handle"? What are you going to do with that?

Comment: Well in my case I want to run an animation (before all redirection)... but feel free to apply the question even to simply execute a single line of code :)

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by this question, but I'll have a go, in the `Page Load` event check `if (Page.IsPostBack == false)` for the postback. Then for the link click, use a `LinkButton` or `HyperLink` then either in the `LinkButton` click event use `Response.Redirect("www.google.co.uk")` or set the `HyperLink.NavigateUrl` property. The browser should deal with url field alteration.

Comment: @ThePower To be honest, I also spent great deal of time thinking on how should I ask this question. But to revert to your comment, your suggestion is indeed possible to be done. Although that means that I have to add a single code for a single `LinkButton` and every single `Respons.Redirect("url")` statement. The idea of my objective is to write once, check once, and handle once and for all. I hope you understand.

Comment: @dotnetjunior Pop it all in a control, then have public properties for the url that will set the navigation properties of the `LinkButton`

Comment: @ThePower I will really appreciate if you can write it down as answer :)..

Comment: Use JavaScript, what Shai wrote is true but you can also achieve the same in pure JavaScript and instead of `alert()` show some animation.

Comment: I am actually thinking to use the UpdateProgress control. Is it also possible?

Comment: I was slightly wrong, the event should be `onbeforeunload` and here is working test case: http://jsfiddle.net/MUYyN/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postback can be handled on the Server Side

the two others - link click or url field are ought to be handled using Javascript only.

UPDATE:
You can use **jQuery** to show a "loading animation" as mentioned in the question

```
$(window).unload( function () { alert("Bye now!"); } );
```

This will issue an alert once the user tries to leave the page. you can change it so it will display an animating gif image.

This must be tested though. I think it's pointless; not too sure on how long the gif will be displayed until the browser starts to load up the new page.

EDIT:

As I mentioned in comments, you can issue a postback using javascript
so, according to my last edit

```
$(window).unload( function () { __doPostBack("leaving"); } );
```

will issue a postback to the server, and you can catch it by:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    this.PreLoad += (sender, args) =>
                        {

                            this.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "arg");

                            if (!IsPostBack) { return; }

                            string __targetaction = this.Request["__EVENTTARGET"];
                            string __args = this.Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];

                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(__args)) return;

                            if (__targetaction == "leaving")
                            {
                                doSomething();
                            }
                        };
}
```

then again, I'm not too sure this will be too helpful, since the user is leaving the page.

Comment: so you are saying, it's impossible to single-handedly handle all these three together?

Comment: Unless you manipulate the client by using JavaScript to issue postbacks when the user tries to access an external link.

Answer (score -1):

**PostBack**
In this Page.IsPostBack will be = true

**Redirection when user click a link in the page**
In this case you will get value in referrer. You can use Request.ServerVariables["http_referer"] OR Request.UrlReferrer

**Redirection when user change url field in the browser**
Else this is the 3rd case